# pandas automatically converting my string column to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What can I do to prevent pandas from converting my string values to float. The column `Billing Doc.` and `Sales Order` contain number 10-11 digit numbers which are to be stored in MySQL table inside a column which has a datatype of CHAR(15). When I execute the following script, I see `.0` at the end of each number. I want to treat them as string/char in our db.
The `Billing Doc.` field contains numbers like `3206790137, 3209056079, 3209763880, 3209763885, 3206790137` who is stored in DB as `3206790137.0, 3209056079.0, 3209763880.0, 3209763885.0, 3206790137.0`. The column data type for Billing doc in database is `CHAR(15)`.

```
def insert_billing(df):
        df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
        for row in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
            bill_item = row['Bill.Item']
            bill_qty = row['Billed Qty']
            bill_doct_date = row['Billi.Doc.Date']
            bill_doc = row['Billing Doc.']
            bill_net_value = row['Billi.Net Value']
            sales_order = row['Sales Order']
            import_date = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


            query = "INSERT INTO sap_billing(" \
                    "bill_item, " \
                    "bill_qty, " \
                    "bill_doc_date, " \
                    "bill_doc, " \
                    "bill_net_value, " \
                    "sales_order, " \
                    "import_date" \
                    ") VALUES (" \
                    "\"{}\", \"{}\", \"{}\", \"{}\"," \
                    "\"{}\", \"{}\", \"{}\"" \
                    ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " \
                    "bill_qty = VALUES(bill_qty), " \
                    "bill_doc_date = VALUES(bill_doc_date), " \
                    "bill_net_value = VALUES(bill_net_value), " \
                    "import_date = VALUES(import_date) " \
                    "".format(
                        bill_item,
                        bill_qty,
                        bill_doct_date,
                        bill_doc,
                        bill_net_value,
                        sales_order,
                        import_date
                        )
            query = query.replace('\"None\"', 'NULL')
            query = query.replace('(None', '(NULL')
            query = query.replace('\"NaT\"', 'NULL')
            query = query.replace('(NaT', '(NULL')

            try:
                q1 = gesdb_connection.execute(query)
            except Exception as e:
                print(bill_item, bill_doc, sales_order, e)



    if __name__ == "__main__":
        engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:abc123@localhost/mydb'

        file_name = "tmp/dataload/so_tracking.XLSX"
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
        if df.shape[1] == 35 and compare_columns(list(df.columns.values)) == 1:
            insert_billing(df)
        else:
            print("Incorrect column count, column order or column headers.\n")
```

When I create a simple df and print it the problem does not show up.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales Order': [1217252835, 1217988754, 1219068439], 
                   'Billing Doc.': [3222102723, 3209781889, 3214305818]})
    >>> df
   Billing Doc.  Sales Order
0    3222102723   1217252835
1    3209781889   1217988754
2    3214305818   1219068439
```

However, when I read through excel and then print it, the column is read as float64.

```
 file_name = "tmp/dataload/so_tracking.XLSX"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    print(df['Billing Doc.'])

680    3.252170e+09
681    3.252170e+09
682    3.252170e+09
683    3.252170e+09
684    3.252170e+09
685    3.252170e+09
686    3.252170e+09
687    3.252170e+09
688    3.252170e+09
689    3.252170e+09
690    3.252170e+09
.
.
.
694    3.251601e+09
695    3.251631e+09
696    3.252013e+09
697             NaN
698    3.252272e+09
699    3.252360e+09
700    3.252474e+09
.
.
Name: Billing Doc., dtype: float64
```

Comment: Could you distill this down to a reproducible example? No one else has access to your database or spreadsheet. So any attempt to help will just be speculation.

Comment: Pandas purists may not like this quick fix, but I use `pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype = object)` and it keeps pandas from converting numbers to floats. I'm fairly certain you can replace `read_csv()` with other DataFrame creating functions.

Comment: @PaulH I added a sample.

Comment: @pshep123. Thanks for your input. It is a .xlsx file and can't be converted into csv as I get it from somewhere else.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you use the `dtype = object` as a `read_excel() ` param. I haven't tested, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: @nomad: read through the answers for the question below and try again. this question needs radical revisions on several levels.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @PaulH I tried showing the problem in a way you mentioned but that way I issue is not there. But when I read the excel using read_excel, the column is read as dtype: float64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution myself, posting here to document it.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, converters={'Billing Doc.' : str})
print(df['Billing Doc.'])

695    3251631331
696    3252012614
697           NaN
698    3252272451
699    3252359504
700    3252473894
701           NaN
702           NaN
703           NaN
704    3252652940
705           NaN
706           NaN
707           NaN
708           NaN
Name: Billing Doc., dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me because the index of new column was not matching the index of original dataframe, which resulted in NaNs, which caused automatic broadcasting to float. Therefore, check if:

- index of original dataframe and the new column matches
- new column contains NaNs.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

*note that this is VERY ineffective*

or convert each value to `int` before insert them into query