# Why pandas adding '.0' at the end of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm processing a csv file. Source file contain value as '20190801'. Pandas detects it as `int` or `float` for different files. But before writing the output, I convert all columns to string and datatype shows all columns as object. But the output containing `.0` at the end. Why is that?

e.g: 20190801.0

```
   for col in data.columns:
        data[col] = data[col].astype(str)
    print(data.dtypes) <-- prints all columns datatypes as object

    data.to_csv(neo_path, index=False)
```

Comment: Numeric strings default to `float` when writing CSV.

Comment: @Barmar, how to avoid that?Due to that issue i was changing all columns datatype to string

Comment: Set the `dtype` to `int64` or `str`

Comment: @Barmar, I think i do that in my above code. Changing all columns datatype to string. astype(str)

Comment: I think there are options to `.to_csv()` that will specify the types in the file.

Comment: hey! do you you have nulls in your data? "Because NaN is a float, this forces an array of integers with any missing values to become floating point." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: @the_good_pony no NULLS. all data like numerics convreted as float

Comment: @Barmar Any example?i couldn't find. Even though I change the type before writing to a file, again do we need to specify?

Comment: @Barmar are you refering to the float_format option in to_csv()?

Comment: No, that's not it. I helped someone a couple of weeks ago with something similar, but I can't find it now. I'm not really a pandas expert.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543131/pandas-automatically-converting-my-string-column-to-float This is about reading excel files. I can't find something similar when writing CSV.

Comment: @Barmar I added the answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like this;
I added converters parameter and making sure all those problematic columns should remain as strings in my case.

```
 data = pd.read_csv(filepath, converters={"SiteCode":str,'Date':str,'Tank ID':str,'SIRA RECORD ID':str}
....
 data.to_csv(neo_path,index=False)
```

In this case I get rid of, converting all column types as string as pointed in my quetsion.

```
 for col in data.columns:
        data[col] = data[col].astype(str)
```

: This didnt work when writing the output to csv. It converts string back again to float

Comment: This answer isn't working for me :(